# Using PHP to return to page after form post

Tags: php

I'm using a form that posts to a PHP script. This then set's a cookie and returns users to the homepage:

HTML form:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  <select name="choice">
    <option value="style1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="style2">2</option>
      <option value="style3">3</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
  $year = 31536000 + time();
  setcookie('style', $_POST['choice'], $year);
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
?>
```

I want to change the behaviour of this script to redirect users to page the form was submitted from.

I've tried adding the following to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="goback" value="<?php echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
```

However I'm unsure how best to change my PHP 'location' to utilise this echo request.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the originating form page as the action for the form?  Just check for $_POST, do your PHP processing, then display the form again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
 <select name="choice">
   <option value="style1" selected>1</option>
   <option value="style2">2</option>
   <option value="style3">3</option>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="goback" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
 <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
```

PHP **update.php**

```
<?php 
    $year = 31536000 + time();
    setcookie('style', $_POST['choice'], $year);
    header('Location:'.$_POST['goback']);
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

For this one

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

It should send users back to the page where they came from.

Comment: There's no rock solid guarantee though that any HTTP Header (including Referer) will actually exist in the request.

Comment: In OP's case it will always exist, won't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, the HTTP REFERER is sent by the browser - it can be blanked, garbled or spoofed. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is simply what the server received from the client.